# How to load view page before executing functions in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

How to load the view page before executing any functions?

App Process:
1. User will click **login button**
2. I will navigate to **sync page**
3. sync page will execute six (6) functions after executing 6 functions it will redirect to my main menu page

The problem is with my number 1 and 2 process. When the user click the login button it will be stuck in my login page then go directly to my main menu page. How can I see the sync page before redirecting to main menu page.

```
public SyncPage (string host, string database, string contactID)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            new Task(SyncSetup).Start();
        }

    async void SyncSetup()
    {
        Deletedata();
        InsertUserData(host, database, contactID);
        InsertCAFData(host, database, contactID);
        InsertContactsData(host, database, contactID);
        InsertActivityData(host, database, contactID);
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
        {
            // Assuming this function needs to use Main/UI thread to move to your "Main Menu" Page
            OnSyncComplete(host, database, contactID);
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would move those functions/processes to a separate thread/task, a super easy way is to use a fire & forget Task and have that task handle those setup processes and then move back to the UI thread in order to move your "Main Menu" page.

Something like this:

```
string contactID; string host; string database;
public SyncPage (string contactID, string host, string database)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.contectID = contactID; this.host = host; this.database = database;
    new Task(SyncSetup).Start(); // Or do this in OnAppearing override
}

protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();
    new Task(SyncSetup).Start(); // This could be an await'd task if need be
}

async void SyncSetup()
{
    Deletedata();
    InsertUserData(host, database, contactID);
    InsertCAFData(host, database, contactID);
    InsertContactsData(host, database, contactID);
    InsertActivityData(host, database, contactID);
    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
    {
        // Assuming this function needs to use Main/UI thread to move to your "Main Menu" Page
        OnSyncComplete(host, database, contactID);
    });
}
```

Comment: There is an error I can't get the `(host, database, contactID)` from `SyncPage (string contactID, string host, string database)`

Comment: @lootverge lol, need more coffee ;-)  Save those parameters to class-level variables before calling the Task.Start().

Comment: Sorry I am new to xamarin can you show me how? please?

Comment: @lootverge Updated my answer, make sense?

Comment: Just to be clear the data inside `SyncPage (string contactID, string host, string database)` came from `Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new SyncPage(hostName, database, contactID), true);`

Comment: @lootverge You are missing the first line in the code section of my answer, those are class level variables to store the three parameters to.

Comment: I have added it I will test it and get back to you